# How to implement Scroll Controller in Flutter (Scroll Widget)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I am trying to implement a Scroll Widget in Flutter but not able to implement it.
   I saw many tutorials but they have implemented scroll widget with ListView or Grid View.
   In my case, I have Register page with multiple Text Inputs and Buttons. In this case, my page is not scrolling down please help someone.

```
div{
   Scroll Widget on the Register page.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SingleChildScrollView` for scrolling like this.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
     child:Column(...)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
class ExampleScroll extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleScrollState createState() => _ExampleScrollState();
}

class _ExampleScrollState extends State<ExampleScroll> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap with a `SingleChildScrollView` `Widget`.
Like this...

```
class AppDashBoard extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
               child: Text('It Scrollable'),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SingleChildScrollView` and provide scrolling contents as its child
for more you can find on the documentation

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

Eg:

```
    SingleChildScrollView(
// scrollable contents as child
         child:Column(...)
    )
```